# pg_ctl on windows: keep running when closing cmd prompt

Tags: postgresql, windows

Is there a way to start postgresql with pg_ctl in a windows command prompt and keep the server running after closing the command prompt?

Note: installed via conda, limited privs eg. running as a service is not an option.

Comment: `start "pg" pg_ctl ....`?

Comment: well this just opens another prompt which when closed stops the server. Idea is to have it in the background completely without a visible window. But I guess that is not possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549442/use-cmd-c-but-hide-the-console-window